# Pandas updating/adding columns to rows incrementally using dictionary key values

Tags: python, pandas

I want to populate columns of a dataframe (df) by iteratively looping over a list (A_list) generating a dictionary where the keys are the names of the desired columns of df (in the example below the new columns are 'C', 'D', and 'E') **NOTE: I have no control over the output of gen_data it's going to return dictionary where keys are column names and values are column values.**

```
import pandas
def gen_data(key):
    #EXAMPLE FUNCTIONS THESE COULD BE ANYTHING AND NOT NECESSARY RELATED TO OTHER COLUMNS
    data_dict = {'C':key+key, 'D':key, 'E':key+key+key}
    return data_dict

A_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f']
df = pandas.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], 'B': [1,2,3,3,2]})

for A_value in A_list:
    data_dict = gen_data(A_value)
    for data_key in data_dict:
        df.loc[df.A == A_value, data_key] = data_dict[key]
```

So the result of this should be:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','f'], 
                       'B': [1,2,3,3,2,1],
                       'C': ['aa','bb','cc','dd',nan,'ff'],
                       'D': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', nan,'f'],
                       'E': ['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd',nan,'fff']})
```

I feel that

```
for data_key in data_dict:
    df.loc[df.A == A_value, data_key] = data_dict[key]
```

is really inefficient if there are a lot of rows in df and I feel that there should be a way to remove the for loop in this code.

```
for A_value in A_list:
    data_dict = gen_data(A_value)
    for data_key in data_dict:
        df.loc[df.A == key, data_key] = data_dict[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have experimented and found that replacing the `for` loop with `try except` block below sped up the computation by a third. The except is used for the very first loop to populate the dataframe with the new columns with out it there would be a mismatch error. It still feels inefficient so I would appreciate any feedback for improvements.

```
import pandas
def gen_data(key):
    #EXAMPLE FUNCTIONS THESE COULD BE ANYTHING AND NOT NECESSARY RELATED TO OTHER COLUMNS
    data_dict = {'C':key+key, 'D':key, 'E':key+key+key}
    return data_dict

A_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f']
df = pandas.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], 'B': [1,2,3,3,2]})

for A_value in A_list:
    data_dict = gen_data(A_value)
    try:
        df.loc[df.A == key] = df.loc[df.A == key].assign(**data_dict)
    except ValueError:
        df = df.reindex(df.columns.tolist() + list(data_dict.keys()))
        df.loc[df.A == file_id] = df.loc[df.A == key].assign(**data_dict)
```

Comment: It's faster both in terms of higher row numbers and higher column numbers